# A question about finding out the error in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I've just downloaded a paper and one of the question asks you to find a solution to the error. I don't know much about visual basic but if you could help, I would really appreciate it. The question states that.I will be doing a project in vb once I learn the language.

The VB code segment shown below is incorrect. Identify the error and write the correct code.[8 Marks]

Illegal Syntax:

```
If HoursDecimal <= 40D Then 
    RegularPayCheckBox.Checked = True 

Else if RegularPayCheckBox.Checked = False 
End If
```

Comment: It probably means for you to type the code into a VB project and find out for yourself what is wrong. That would be the most instructive.

Comment: Make sure Option Strict is on.

Comment: You might find this page insightful [Open letter to Students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 potential problems in your syntax

```
If HoursDecimal <= 40D Then
```

you are comparing less than or equal to a string (without quotes also), or decimal which given variable name makes it likely correct; remove the D - unless this is a decimal

```
RegularPayCheckBox.Checked = True
```

no issues in this part

```
Else if RegularPayCheckBox.Checked = False
```

should not be else if unless it is an expression you are trying to compare (similar to a regular if statement. but rather an Else statement

End If

no issues in this part

so a working example would be

```
If HoursDecimal <= 40D Then 
    RegularPayCheckBox.Checked = True 
Else 
    RegularPayCheckBox.Checked = False 
End If
```

Good luck and it would probably be helpful next time to generate a project and paste the code - your errorlist and intelisense will give direction towards an answer on most problems you have.

Comment: The error with HoursDecimal is that has not been declared. Since it is called HoursDecimal I would assume it was meant to be declared as a Decimal. `Dim HoursDecimal As Decimal`.

Comment: `Else if RegularPayCheckBox.Checked = False ` simply needs a Then at the end of the line to be syntactically correct; however I believe your correction is the logically correct answer.

Comment: `40D` is a valid literal decimal value. I don't think there's anything wrong on that line.

Comment: @Mary I don't think the declaration of HoursDecimal comes into it: there's the whole of the rest of the program missing if so.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `if` from this line:

```
Else if RegularPayCheckBox.Checked = False
```

But I personally would simplify the code, and reduce the entire If/Else block down to just this:

```
RegularPayCheckBox.Checked = (HoursDecimal <= 40D)
```